# Intel Xeon Phi 7120p on 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I recently bought Intel Xeon Phi 7120p and plugged it into a computer running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The card shows up in lspci, but then I don't know what to do next.

Should I install updated MPSS modules from [here](https://github.com/pentschev/mpss-modules), or do I use (experimental) `mic_card` and `mic_host` modules provided with upstream kernel? (The utilities from Intel MPSS are often checking for the `mic` module, not for the newer ones.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably like to take a look at [this](http://arrayfire.com/getting-started-with-the-intel-xeon-phi-on-ubuntu-14-04linux-kernel-3-13-0/) article.

Comment: Try to include the relevant parts instead of simple posting links as your answer. Links are better suited as comments.